# Predict a quantity for a date

Tags: python, machine-learning

Based on a certain day of the week, and whether or not an entry occurred, I'm looking to predict what items we'd ship using some model.

Here's an example of the data

```
11/05/2019    Apple        1
11/17/2019    Curry        9
11/06/2019    Pasta        10
```

Where you have the date, the item, and the quantity of item shipped. Mostly, these are at 1-4 item intervals each.

I'm rather new to python and machine learning, here's the textbook that I'm attempting to use:
http://index-of.es/Varios-2/Hands%20on%20Machine%20Learning%20with%20Scikit%20Learn%20and%20Tensorflow.pdf

So far, I have imported the data into jupyter and created a training set of 80% of the values. I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: Consider [Facebook Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/)

Comment: Hope this can help you out: https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-sales-611cb5a252de

Comment: @user1558604 Prophet takes in only 2 columns of data. I need to know which product needs what quantity.

Comment: @bohzwah, you'd probably want a seperate model for each item anyway. Though rereading your question, I'm not sure it will be the best for you. I though you were looking for a simple timeseries prediction

Comment: @user1558604 Just looking for a model that, based on the day, spits out how much inventory you should purchase for that day. So demand forecasting models.

Comment: Yeah, Prophet might work for you. You'd simply have a separate model for each item.

Comment: @user1558604 Prophet takes an x and y, not an x, y and z. Unless I'm misunderstanding how Prophet works.

Comment: What would your Z be?  You'd have the date and you have the quantity. You'd do that for each item separately.

Comment: @user1558604 That's true, I didn't think of that. But what if you have 100 items? Is there a way to streamline that? My immediate thought is to create 100 CSV files and import all of them, but that sounds incredibly tedious.

Comment: @bohzwah, Can you use pandas with Prophet?  You could read in a single CSV, use `for df in pandas.groupby("item").groups:` to form the prophet models in a loop.

Comment: @user1558604 OK, I'll play with that. Thanks for the recommendation.